# Sard's theorem, upper bound for coefficients of Taylor series

Tags: measure-theory, taylor-expansion, differential-topology

Hi I am stuck in proofs of Sard's theorem. Whenever I try to find a proof, the following statement gets used.

If $C \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is a closed cube and $C_k$ the set of critical points, such that all of its partial derivatives of order less or equal than $k$ vanish.
Then for every critical point $x \in C_k \cap C $ there is a constant a only depending on $C$ and $f$, such that $\lVert f(x+h)-f(x) \rVert \leq a \lVert h \rVert ^k
$.

Why does $a$ not depend on $x$?

Here would be an example where this statement gets used, but all the sources I check use this.
[https://www.google.com/url?q=http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/21F-Manifolds/Notes/Lec07.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwi-9tmnoPb6AhUxX_EDHXOrDVEQFnoECAcQAg&usg=AOvVaw2RTXRARz-3-_prrGtJLOLZ](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ewangzuoq/Courses/21F-Manifolds/Notes/Lec07.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwi-9tmnoPb6AhUxX_EDHXOrDVEQFnoECAcQAg&usg=AOvVaw2RTXRARz-3-_prrGtJLOLZ)

Comment: Sard's, not Sards theorem (I have corrected it)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why the a is a bound that does not depend on the choice of x inside C and Q.

Comment: Derivative is a continuous function on compact set so it will be bounded and thus the difference quotients must be bounded locally. Pull back to finite number of bounds via compactness and choose the biggest. (If it's not differentiable I think you can get the bound desired by combining the bounds on all the partial derivatives, but it should be a bit more messy). We get the (at least partial) differentiability from being on critical points, and compactness from $C$; the intersection thus has both properties.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just noticed that a $k$ was missing.   The problem I was having with this case is that it is true for individual critical points. I dont see how i can use continuity of partial derivatives in this case, because the partial derivatives of lower order only vanish at the critical points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor’s formula for functions of one variable gives $$g(1)=g(0)+\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n!}g^{(n)}(0)+\frac{1}{(k+1)!}g^{(k+1)}(c)$$ for some $c$ in $(0,1)$. Now if you apply it to the function $g(t)=f(x+th)$, $t\in [0,1]$, by the chain rule you find $$f(x+h)=f(x)+\frac1{(k+1)!}\sum\frac1{\alpha!}\partial^\alpha f(x+ch)h^\alpha$$ where the sum is done over all multi-indexes of length $k+1$. Now, since $C$ is compact, all these derivatives are bounded in $C$ by a constant $M$, that is
$$|\partial^\alpha f(y)|\le M$$ for all $y$ in $C$ and all multi-indexes of length $k+1$.
This is why $a$ does not depend on $x$. You take
$$a=\frac1{(k+1)!}\sum\frac1{\alpha!}M$$

If $f$ Is vector valued, it has more than one component. In this case, you can apply this estimate to each component.